# Unit under test reads past end of buffer - how to ensure test fails?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have written a unit test for some method `foo()` that could be simplified to something like

```
int foo(Bar *obj)
{
    char buffer[2];

    readDataIntoBuffer(buffer, 2);

    return obj->processData((int*)buffer);
}
```

The problem with `foo()` is that `sizeof(int)` is 4 on my platform, so that it reads past the end of the buffer.

In my unit tests I validate that `processData` is called (on a mocked version of Bar) with a pointer pointing to the expected value. But my problem is that it is flaky. My guess is, that it depends on the somewhat random contents of the memory in the two bytes following the buffer. If they happen to be zero the test passes but if they don't it fails since `processData` gets called with some random value.

How do I make sure that my test always fails? Am I at all correct in testing that `processData` gets called with the expected value or should I not care?

In case it matters I am using gcc version 4.8.4 [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) and [googlemock](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock).

Comment: As alternative, You may run some static tools analysis and forbid C-Cast.

Comment: @nwp Yes, makes sense. I tried to use Asan with gcc by compiling and linking with `-fsanitize=address` but it does not detect the out-of-bounds-read. UBsan is only available starting with gcc 4.9, unfortunately.

Comment: @nwp Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? I guess using UBsan to make my test abort is the correct answer to my question, although I cannot implement it since it is not available to me ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior. By definition anything can happen, including the behavior that the test expects or that the test is skipped, so there is no way from within the program to make the test always fail.

I recommend [Asan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) + [UBsan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) or similar tools to make the behavior defined and testable.